# how to set folder path for gtags

Tags: emacs, tags, gnu-global

I am new to gtags, and have a question. I have a big project, such as android AOSP, I want gtags to parse some folders, how can I achieve it with gtags? I searched and got solution:

1. use -f option with gtags, it seems doesn't support folders

Is there any good idea that I can set the folders path and gtags only process those folders?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UPDATE: author of the question came up with a better solution in the comments. I'm adding it here so it's easier to find:

> .. create tag file in the sub-directories I need, and add the directories
>   to GTAGSLIBPATH when loading the project,

---

My answer:

You can  limit what gtags indexes by adding list of files/directories to **skip** keyword in ~/.globalrc or /etc/gtags.conf. Here's a sample gtags.conf file.

The problem is that often global/gtags packages don't install gtags.conf (at least it's not there in global-5.7.1-2 on ubuntu 12.04), so you'll need to either get it from global source distribution, or use someone else's gtags.conf as a reference. For instance [here](http://www.geocities.jp/keep_creating/sanaly/gtags.conf).

Something like this should work. Note that leading `/` means `from the top of the tree`. Without it gtags will skip matching entries anywhere in the tree.:

```
common:\
    :skip=/skip-this-dir/,/lib/and-this/,/include/and-this-one-too/:
```

Comment: Thanks, it sounds like some global settings, not restricted to single project. If manipulating several projects, will they share the same skip setting? Maybe I don't understand gtags.

Comment: Yup. It's global. Pun intended. :-/

Comment: I have found an alternative, I can create tag file in the sub-directories I need, and add the directories to GTAGSLIBPATH when loading the project, it works for me.

Comment: Great! I didn't think of that. It may be good idea to update your question (or add an answer of your own?) so your solution is not lost in the comments.

Comment: For anyone as late to this party as myself, gnu global (at least as of 6.5.6) looks for a gtags.conf in the project root. Hence, you can use the solution of @ArtemB and just set the skips for this project. This way you don't have to set any env vars on project load - it should just work.

Answer (score 2):

The -f option is premised on find(1). Please try the followings.

```
$ find folder1 folder2 folder3 -type f -print | gtags -f -
```

or

```
$ find folder1 folder2 folder3 -type f -print >gtags.files
$ gtags
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my bash function to get rid of files and paths including 'dummy' and 'win':

```
function gtagsupdate { 
find . -name "*.c" -o -name "*.cpp" -o -name "*.h" -o -name "*.hpp" | grep -v dummy | grep -v win | gtags -f -
}
```